# folder is used by another task when try to delete it

Tags: android, macos, osx-yosemite

I am using MacBook for my Android project development. I have my android-sdk-v1 downloaded under path `~/MySDKs/android-sdk-v1/`. I have added ANDROID_HOME in `.bash_profile`.

Today, I downloaded an newer version SDK to ~/MySDKs/android-sdk-v2/ . I changed all the environment variables in `.bash_profile` to this new path.

Then I moved the old android-sdk-v1 to trash can. Then I choose "empty trash". But system pops up an dialog says teh android-sdk-v1 can not be deleted due to it is used by another task.

My question is how to check which task is using it & stop the task in OS X ?

Answer (score 0):

Access the Mac Task Manager. Activity Monitor is located in your /Applications/Utilities/ directory. You need to eject the installation of that sdk by pulling up finder.